# Unable to solve linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging, xib

I already added libPods library into my project.

but why linker command failed with exit code 1 error occurs on running time

my screenshot are given below-
[image]

[image]

please help me

Comment: Open .xcworkspace white coloured file not blue coloured .xcodeproject file.

Comment: deintegrate the pod library add it again the same library. it will work

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P sir how i deintegrate the pod library and again integrate please give me some tips

Comment: have installed the cocopod in your system

Comment: @WasimSafdar sir same issue occurred in .xcworkspace

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P yes sir..by terminal i have installed cocoa pod

Comment: install it first "$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods-deintegrate"

Comment: follow the procedure refer the link :https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Comment: Sometimes, you need to define minimum deployment target in pod file.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P thanks a lot sir..

Comment: same pod file to add your framework and run it